# TypeError when saving a file in PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am trying to change the hue of the image in Pillow and then save it. Basically the code below iterates over each pixel and sets its hue. The code works with most of the files, but for some reason, some files cause a TypeError when saving them.

```
im = Image.open("fire_layer_0.png")
im = im.convert("HSV")
def change_hue(image):
    for x in range(image.width):
        for y in range(image.height):
            print("sh")
            s = image.getpixel((x, y))[1]
            v = image.getpixel((x, y))[2]
            color = (190, s, v)
            image.putpixel((x, y), color)
change_hue(im)
output = im.convert("RGB")
print(output)
output.save("firetest", 'PNG')
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2084, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 871, in _save
    red, green, blue = transparency
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Help with the problem and suggestions to improve the code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are your images in any chance grayscaled? Try once with `im = Image.open("fire_layer_0.png").convert('RGB')`

Comment: There are many issues with your code. You have removed all the `import` statements so it cannot work. You are using `for` loops which you will see is not a good approach if you look at any if the last 300 questions on PIL on StackOverflow. You never return a result from your function. Please look at some other questions/answers.

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev The image actually had transparent pixels. Thanks for your suggestion, it helped a lot.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The import statements are there, I just didn't include them here. As for the loop approach, I do understand it's not the fastest. However, my images are 16x16, so it doesn't matter as much. This is also my first day of using PIL and I do not quite understand the whole thing yet, even after looking at other questions, such as image.point and stuff like that. I appreciate your criticism though.

Comment: It's late here, I'll try and take a look tomorrow if no-one else helps out.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I figured it out with the help of the first person already, the problem was that some images had transparent pixels and converting them from HSV to RGB and then saving that didn't work. The only question I have now is how to maintain the transparency in HSV mode. Meaning that when I convert to RGBA, I want the originally transparent pixels remain transparent, but they become black.

Comment: See `getchannel()` to save alpha and `im.putalpha()` to restore it here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/56197189/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for your and others' help, I believe I got the script working efficiently and I am satisfied with the outcome. Thank you again.