# Using python to fill an image with one color in steps from 0% to 100%

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a black image that I need to **fill with a new color**.

I want to generate new images starting from 1% to 100% (generating an
image for every 1% filled).

#### Examples for 4 fill-ratios

- Heart image filled with 1%, 5%, 10% and 15%

[image: Heart image filled with 1%, 5%, 10% and 15%]

#### Research I did

I did a lot of research on the internet and the closest I came was this link:

[Fill an image with color but keep the alpha (Color overlay in PIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196592/fill-an-image-with-color-but-keep-the-alpha-color-overlay-in-pil)

However, as I don't have much experience with Python for image editing, I couldn't move forward or modify the code as needed.

Edit:
I was trying with this code from the link

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open image
im = Image.open('2746646.png')

# Make into Numpy array
n = np.array(im)

# Set first three channels to red
n[..., 0:3] = [ 255, 0, 0 ]

# Convert back to PIL Image and save
Image.fromarray(n).save('result.png')
```

But it only generates a single image (as if it were 100%, I need 100 images with 1% filled in each one).

Comment: Which code from the link did you try, what was the reason it doesn't meet your expectations?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I updated the post with the information.

Comment: Is it always a heart shape? Other representative shapes? Must it always fill from the bottom towards the top? Does 15% filled mean 15% of the black pixels or 15% of the black rows?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment, follow the answers: there will be several different shapes, however, all with the same width and height. Always filled from the bottom up and 15% represents 15% of the shape's height pixels.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**

Now you have shared your actual starting image, it seems you don't really want to replace black pixels, but actually opaque pixels. If you split your image into its constituent RGBA channels and lay them out left-to-right R,G,B then A, you can see you want to fill where the alpha (rightmost) channel is white, rather than where the RGB channels are black:

[image]

That changes the code to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load image, ensure not palettised, and make into Numpy array
im = Image.open('muscle.png').convert('RGBA')
# Make Numpy array
RGBA = np.array(im)
# Get RGB part
RGB = RGBA[..., :3]
# Get greyscale version of image as Numpy array
alpha = RGBA[..., 3]
# Find X,Y coordinates of all black pixels in image
blkY, blkX = np.where(alpha==255)
# Just take one entry per row, even if multiple black pixels in it
uniqueRows = np.unique(blkY)
# How many rows are there with black pixels in?
nUniqueRows = len(uniqueRows)
for percent in range(2,101):
    # Work out filename based on percentage
    filename = f'result-{percent:03d}.png'
    # How many rows do we need to fill?
    nRows = int(nUniqueRows * percent/100.0)
    # Which rows are they? Negative index because filling bottom-up.
    rows = uniqueRows[-nRows:]
    print(f'DEBUG: filename: {filename}, percent: {percent}, nRows: {nRows}, rows: {rows}')
    # What are the indices onto blkY, blkX ?
    indices = np.argwhere(np.isin(blkY, rows))
    # Make those pixels black
    RGB[blkY[indices.ravel()], blkX[indices.ravel()], :3] = [0,255,0]
    res = Image.fromarray(RGBA).save(filename)
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

That was fun! This seems to work - though it's not that efficient. It is not a true *"floodfill"*, see note at end.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load image, ensure not palettised, and make into Numpy array
im = Image.open('heart.png').convert('RGB')
# Make Numpy array
na = np.array(im)
# Get greyscale version of image as Numpy array
grey = np.array(im.convert('L'))
# Find X,Y coordinates of all black pixels in image
blkY, blkX = np.where(grey==0)
# Just take one entry per row, even if multiple black pixels in it
uniqueRows = np.unique(blkY)
# How many rows are there with black pixels in?
nUniqueRows = len(uniqueRows)
for percent in range(1,101):
    # Work out filename based on percentage
    filename = f'result-{percent:03d}.png'
    # How many rows do we need to fill?
    nRows = int(nUniqueRows * percent/100.0)
    # Which rows are they? Negative index because filling bottom-up.
    rows = uniqueRows[-nRows:]
    # print(f'DEBUG: filename: {filename}, percent: {percent}, nRows: {nRows}, rows: {rows}')
    # What are the indices onto blkY, blkX ?
    indices = np.argwhere(np.isin(blkY, rows))
    # Make those pixels green
    na[blkY[indices.ravel()], blkX[indices.ravel()], :] = [0,255,0]
    res = Image.fromarray(na).save(filename)
```

[image]

---

Note that this isn't actually a true *"flood fill"* - it is more naïve than that - because it doesn't seem necessary for your image. If you add another shape, it will fill that too:

[image]

Comment: Thank so much about this, but, when I try to use with .png without a background, these images generate a totally green, check this image out https://imgur.com/a/y5lM1Wa, please, and thank again for help.

Comment: Please share a proper representative starting image. Thank you.

Comment: Here some sample images and thanks

Heart
https://imgur.com/a/o0RJH8q

Muscle
https://imgur.com/a/eQp36Fh

Book
https://imgur.com/a/Wr4wXY5

Comment: I have updated the answer to accommodate your actual images. Please have another look.